# x-systemd.device-timeout in fstab seems not to have effect

Tags: fstab

In the fstab I have the line

```
LABEL="scratch"                     /home/frank/ScratchLV ext4 defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=9 0 0
```

but whenever the system boots and the disk is not present, it waits for 90s till the process continues. My understanding is that the wait should be only 9s, as indicated in the fstab line.

What is wrong with my fstab?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, I know. But, for the sake of whoever comes here with a similar problem: did you run "systemctl daemon-reload" after editing your fstab? Your changes will have no effect until you (or some other process) do that (since you're using a systemd-infected system...)

BTW, a simple number after the "=" is interpreted as seconds; there's no need for the "s" after the number.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Possible, that I did not run `systemctl-daemon-reload`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be `x-systemd.device-timeout=9s` for it to work.

Comment: thanks, i will try this - the manual (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) seems to indicate that a figure is interpreted as seconds. unfortunately, it will be a while before I can try it.